# Watir-scroll gives an error when scrolling to element

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

Just got an unknown error when I try to `scroll.to` a specific element. For example with:

```
@browser.scroll.to page_element_xy
#=> "Don't know how to scroll to: #< Watir::Div:0x... >! (ArgumentError)"
```

The normal `scroll.to` `:top` / `:bottom` is still working somehow.

Is just the DIV the problem or has the `scroll.to` function changed in general?

On search, I found the following that worked for me:

```
page_element_xy.scroll.to :center
```

Would be nice to know what is recommended for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of [Watir-Scroll v0.2](https://github.com/p0deje/watir-scroll/commit/bf1bc3988939455979a2c6ccb9b57b96f8683309), the browser-level scrolling no longer supports scrolling to an element.

The equivalent of:

```
@browser.scroll.to page_element_xy
```

Is now:

```
page_element_xy.scroll.to :top
```

Scrolling to the top of the element is the default, so you can simply do:

```
page_element_xy.scroll.to
```

Comment: Makes sense and makes it easy, thank you, also for very fast answer as always

Comment: Can you accept the answer so people will know it has been answered?